# Python Web scraping Intranet won't proceed after login

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib, python-requests-html

I am new to Python webscraping, rest api, html. First of all I have to say that there are many different solutions similar to my question. But my question is with Intranet website and not similar to the any of other questiosn. I researched almost every link since days and after all failed attempts, I am posting this question as I did not get any help. Please do consider my efforts and do not mark it duplicate or unwanted question.

1. ***Background Requirement:***

I am trying to automate some column IDs from an internal website. For this, I am using python Web scraping to get the list of IDs of a particular column and then set them to on or off. For example, if an ID matches the ID from an excel file I have in my local, I should toggle the status column (parallel to that ID) in that intranet portal as on or off. For this, I am using ***requests*** library. And this intranet website works only after I give specific username, password authentication.

2. ***Problem:***

The problem is that I am unable to login to that web portal and then navigate to the page I require using web scraping. All I get is just some part of 'View source code' html script as output. Even when I directly scrape the navigated webpage I want (with payload as username, password), I still get only this home page data. Can anyone suggest me how do I solve scraping the data from the webpage I want after login? I am not sure if I successfully am able to login, because I just get html ***response <200>*** as the status code after login. I understand it is a success code that the website is found. But then I am not able to see any data how it looks after login. The scraped data is home page before login.

3. ***Result:***

Output scraped data:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="lm.login.application" class="lm-scroll-bar html-overflow" ng-strict-di>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content='width=device-width,height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, target-densitydpi=device-dpi'/>
    <link rel="icon" href="../favicon.ico?ui-version=12.0.40.12" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/ui/generated/webpack/authpoint.beaf402df60c88783fc6.min.css?ui-version=12.0.40.12"/>
    <script>
        var lmSession = {
            buildVersion: '76',
            redirectTarget: 'https\x3A\x2F\x2F<intanet_webportal_>\x2Dprod.<intanet_address_>group.net\x2Fui\x2F',
            language: 'english',
            userLanguageCode: 'en',
            isMLU: false,
            isProduction: true,
            isExternalAuthModeEnabled: false,
            productBrandEditionDisplayName: 'EDITION PLACEHOLDER',
            logLevel: 'error',
            siteParams: {"LOGIN_PAGE_NAME_LABEL": ""},
            loginNotice: '\x3Cdiv\x20style\x3D\x22font\x2Dsize\x3A120\x25\x3Bcolor\x3Ared\x3B\x22\x3EZur\x20erstmaligen\x20Nutzung\x20seit\x20dem\x20Update\x20Strg\x20\x2B\x20F5\x20dr\xFCcken\x20um\x20den\x20Seiten\x20Cache\x20zu\x20l\xF6schen.\x3C\x2Fdiv\x3E\x3Cbr\x3EWelcome\x20using\x20\x3Ca\x20href\x3D\x22http\x3A\x2F\x2F<intanet_webportal_>.<intanet_address_>group.net\x2F\x22\x20style\x3D\x22background\x2Dcolor\x3A\x23ffffa0\x22\x3ETAEE\x20Next\x3C\x2Fa\x3E\x20via\x20<intanet_webportal_>.\x3Cbr\x3E\x3Ca\x20href\x3D\x22https\x3A\x2F\x2Fvts4.<intanet_address_>group.net\x2Fsites\x2Ftundaee\x2F<intanet_webportal_>\x2FDocuments\x2FTAEE\x2DNext\x2520\x2D\x2520Disclaimer.pdf\x3FWeb\x3D1\x22\x20style\x3D\x22background\x2Dcolor\x3A\x23ffffa0\x22\x3EErkl\xE4rung\x20zum\x20Datenschutz\x2FPrivacy\x20notice\x3C\x2Fa\x3E\x20\x3Cbr\x3E\x3Ca\x20href\x3D\x22https\x3A\x2F\x2Fvts4.<intanet_address_>group.net\x2Fsites\x2Ftundaee\x2F<intanet_webportal_>\x2FDocuments\x2FNUTZUNGSBEDINGUNGEN\x2520TAEE\x2DNext.pdf\x22\x20style\x3D\x22background\x2Dcolor\x3A\x23ffffa0\x22\x3ENutzungsbedingungen\x3C\x2Fa\x3E'
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="lm.login.application.controller">

<noscript>
    <div class="browser-misconfig-alert">LM requires that JavaScript be enabled in your browser</div>
</noscript>

<script src="/ui/generated/webpack/authpoint.17231e2531a66bfe2e17.min.js"></script>

<div class="ng-cloak" class="web-ui-login-main-wrapper">
    <div class="web-ui-login-wrapper">
        <ng-include src="'login-app.html?ui-version=12.0.40.12'"></ng-include>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>


Process finished with exit code 0`
```

I am able to scrape only this much inspite of all my attempts. But not logging in or natigvate to next page after login and get the field I want.

***Methods tried:***

- Python requests(get, post) with and without session object
- Beautiful Soup
- Mechanize Browser
- Mechanize Soup
  -urlopen (urllib)
- selenium (webdriver)
- Network folder under 'Inpect Element' with session details

With all these methods, I get only this html data that I showed above. There is no *csrf token* for my website. It has only *xsrf header*.

[image: InspectElement]

Could someone be kind to explain me where am I failing and how can I login, navigate and then get the data by python scraping. I am bound to use only Python due to internal constraints. I understand that, a response of ***200*** as status code does not mean it is successfully logged in with given user id and password.

Anyhelp would be really highly appreciated. A million ton thanks!! This will be a ***life saving issue***.

***As this is intranet webportal, I changed the names, so as not to disclose the data. Hope you understand***

Comment: It seems, that the website pages are generated using client side javascript. There is even `noscript` tag with a message "LM requires that JavaScript be enabled in your browser". Could you post your code using selenium and describe the issues with this approach?

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://xxxxxxx.net/")

username = browser.find_element_by_id("inputusername")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("password")
submit = browser.find_element_by_id("Log In")
username.send_keys("user")
password.send_keys("password")
submit.click()

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="inputusername"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.111)

Comment: Thank you for your reply alexandra. I have pasted the selenium code which I used

Comment: @AlexandraDudkina I have also used another selenium method. But I guess I am failing to find 'find_elements_by_tag_name' or 'find_elements_by_tag_id' or 'find_elements_by_tag_class' and hence unable to sendkeys as '<userid>

Comment: Also, Javascript is activated in my chrome browser. I have checked

Comment: Method 2:
def get_url_cookie(driver):
    driver.get('https://octane-prod.bmwgroup.net/')
    login = "input-large ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched"
    id = "inputUsername"
    html_source = driver.page_source
    block = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('div')
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "inputUsername")))
    finally:
        driver.quit()
  
driver = get_driver()
get_url_cookie(driver)
    block = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('div')

Comment: ###Output of 'block'###
 #<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="61c8e44ef8732adf0ec7448f774e5e3a", element="a3b6279b-a492-426f-812b-cda5ee9997d7")>

Comment: ####Error I get####selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".login-form"}
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.111)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selenium approach seems correct to me. Here is a slightly adjusted version of your code. Please check element selectors. Main idea is to wait for each element you need using WebDriverWait and scroll to it before performing any actions. For buttons it may be useful to use `EC.element_to_be_clickable` instead of `EC.presence_of_element_located`.

After retrieving some container element you can use `print(element.get_attribute('innerHTML'))` for debugging reasons.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# delay for selenium web driver wait
DELAY = 30

# create selenium driver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
#chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('<<PATH_TO_CHROMEDRIVER>>', options=chrome_options)

# open web page
driver.get('<<URL>>')

# maximize window
driver.maximize_window()

# wait for username input, scroll to it, enter username
username = WebDriverWait(driver, DELAY).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "inputusername")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", username)
username.send_keys("user") 

# wait for password input, scroll to it, enter password
password = WebDriverWait(driver, DELAY).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "password")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", password)
password.send_keys("password")

# wait for submit button, scroll to it, click it
submit = WebDriverWait(driver, DELAY).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "login")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", submit)
submit.click()

# quit driver
#driver.quit()
```

If there will be any problems, it would be helpful to add HTML sources of the login page (using previously described `element.get_attribute('innerHTML')` approach).

Comment: Thank you million tons @AlexandraDudkina. Now I am able to login by modifying your code. Could you please suggest me some good tutorial or website where I can get some guidance on this. Because I am unable to get clearly or decide the tags to get by class or ID or tagname  to scrape the data after navigating to the required page inside the portal.

Comment: Also could you please explain me little more about element.get_attribute('innerHTML') approach. I am still unclear what you mentioned. Probably an example might help me

Comment: Can someone help me to guide how do I navigate after logging in and scrape the data present in it?

Comment: Is there any reason why using "find_element_by_id/name/classname" does not work here, but rather works well with "EC.presence_of_element_located". What was my mistake in that code

Comment: The main reason why "find_element_by_id/name/classname" doesn't work is that HTML is loaded dynamically by javascript and at the moment, when you call "find_element_by_smth" the element may not exist yet. Therefore it's much safer to use "presence_of_element_located" or similar expressions. There may be other pitfalls, e.g. element may be located outside of the screen, may be covered with another element etc.

Comment: As for knowledge sources I would recommend [this one](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and [this one](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/index.html). Selenium is mostly used for test automation, so it may have sense to take a look at couple of test automation guides.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation Alexandra! It helps me understand better

Comment: I then tried to navigate to the page I want after logging in using selenium. But unfortunately that is making me stay only on the page before logging in and is not allowing me to login itself. Even if the scrape the data, I get only the login page html data

Comment: driver.get("< URL Link to page where I wish to navigate after successful logging in>")
url = driver.current_url
driver.get(url)
source = driver.page_source

Comment: Usually after login browser is redirected to another web page. If that's the case for your web site, there is no need to navigate webdriver to this page programatically.